# iOS devices displaying iframe video smaller

Tags: ios, css, iframe, video

I am having a problem with a kickstarter video that I am embedding. It works fine on everything except iOS devices. The iframe container is the correct size but when the video plays it is scaled down by about 25%.

I have done some research and tried fixing it but nothing is working for me. It appears as if it is a CSS conflict.

Here is a screenshot from my iPad:

http://louisreed.co.uk/tiddlybot/screenshot.png

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1320310506/tiddlybot-fun-and-simple-raspberry-pi-robot/widget/video.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container {
width: 75%;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.embed-container { 
height: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.embed-container iframe { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome, cheers!

Comment: remove the attributes `width` and `height` from your `<iframe>` tag since you set them in your CSS

Comment: @Oliboy50 Thanks but it is still doing the same thing!

Comment: what about removing the `padding-bottom` property in `.embed-container` CSS ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 Removing the 'padding-bottom' property makes the video and container disappear altogether.